# Load page only if image containing specified class exists

Tags: javascript, ajax

For example, I want to load www.haha.com only if an image with class I specified, exists within that page.If it doesn't exist, load something else.Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Elements may have more than one class assigned to them. In HTML, this is represented by separating the class names with a space:

```
<div id="mydiv" class="foo bar"></div>
```

The `.hasClass()` method will return `true` if the class is assigned to an element, even if other classes also are. For example, given the HTML above, the following will return true:

```
$( "#mydiv" ).hasClass( "foo" )
```

As would:

```
$( "#mydiv" ).hasClass( "bar" )
```

While this would return `false`:

```
$( "#mydiv" ).hasClass( "quux" )
```

For detailed docs visit https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

To answer your question:

```
if ($( "#mydiv" ).hasClass( "foo" )) {
    // load some web page
} else {
    // load other web page
}
```

**Update**

Load web pages until requires CSS `class` is found.

```
do {
    // load some web page
    // implement logic to choose which page to load
} while (! $( "#mydiv" ).hasClass( "foo" ));
```

Comment: Ok, lets say I want to go to random page using function for generating random URL.If an image with class="hello" doesn't exist withing that page,I don't load it.I use function for random URL again until I find page which contains image with class="hello".Is this possible to do?